# App Engine appstats performance tuning

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Latency for my application seems to be very high even though I've optimized it significantly.

Here is an appstats sample for one of the requests:

```
(4) 2013-01-16 08:33:19.750 "GET /" 200 real=3154ms api=0ms overhead=12ms (39 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
images.GetUrlBase   18  0   
memcache.Get            10  0   
datastore_v3.Get    9   0   
datastore_v3.RunQuery   1   0   
user.CreateLogoutURL    1   0
```

Seems images.GetUrlBase is one of the main culprit as well as memcache (?).
Currently I have blob being fetched and passed to get_serving_url, with variable image sizes throughout the application.

Any recommendation on performance improvements? thanks

Comment: figured out the main problem is in fact the get_serving_url, because its fetching the blob file and passing in the key each time. any ideas on caching methods for this particular situation?

Comment: nevermind, fixed the latency issue

Comment: how did you fix the issue.. for me, it shows: `"POST /search" 200 real=16195ms api=0ms overhead=0ms (29 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])` and `datastore_v3.RunQuery 3 0 
logservice.Flush 3 0 
user.CreateLogoutURL 1 0 `

Comment: I recommend to stop and do not use google app engine for anything. I spent over a year developing on that platform, with constant issues and bottlenecks. For small apps, yes, for anything big, no. To give you the answer, caching, caching and caching, and intelligent caching. The rule of thumb, if I remember is to try to make it so that you get all from cache with a single hit to memcache. Caching on app engine, itself, takes a performance hit when you try to get from the cache, it's a constant pitfall of issues. Think deep on how to design it.